# Phosphorus and Boron groups

Tags: organic-chemistry, pnictogen

I know some sulfur groups such as sulfones and disulfides and sulfonic acids. I also know of 1 phosphorus group. That is the phosphate ion.
I don't know of any boron groups.

What is the phosphorus equivalent of aldehydes, ketones, and carboxylic acids?

Phosphals, Phosphones, and Phosphonic acids I suppose?

And what about the boron equivalent of aldehydes, ketones, and carboxylic acids?

Comment: For phosphorus, one analogy between carbon and phosphorus compounds is the following:

Carbonate -> carboxylate -> acetal* -> alcohol -> alkane

Phosphate -> phosphonate -> phosphonite -> phosphinite -> phosphine

Note that I put acetal instead of ketone/aldehyde because it is a better analogy to phosphonite.  A few cool P-containing functional groups like phosphine oxides and phosphorus ylides don't map cleanly into that analogy though, so don't think the list is exhaustive.

Comment: Please don't try to summarise your question with tags. For more information, see [meta.se](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878/260760) and the [help].

Comment: Boron-oxygen double bonds are not very stable so I doubt any direct boron analogues have been prepared.

Comment: I didn't think I was summarizing with tags. I just thought that putting in a phosphorus tag and a boron tag along with the organic chemistry tag would attract people who know about phosphorus and boron functional groups so that I could get an answer faster.

Comment: There is no such thing like phosphals, phosphones and its boron equivalent but [phosphonic acid](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=TBgXWIzhDeqK8QefjLY4#q=Phosphonic+acids) and [boronic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boronic_acid) do exist.